# C++: This code compiles, but throws Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'num' was corrupted. occurred

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, char, runtime-error

When the code executes the variable num get the value `'9'`, then the error occurs.

```
char num = 'A';
int* pnum = (int *)&num;
*pnum = '9';
```

What does the error mean?

Comment: The error is correct this is undefined behavior. You are corrupting the stack. Here you are likely writing a 4 byte value into a variable that is 1 byte.

Comment: With Undefined Behaviour, everything is possible. It's very nice of the compiler/environment that you get an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting and using a pointer like this is undefined behavior. You can't just take a pointer to a `char` and pretend that it's pointing to an `int` and expect it to work correctly. In all likelyhood the stack is getting corrupted because an `int` takes more memory than a `char`, so by doing `*pnum = '9';`, you're writing to invalid memory. `char` has size `1`, but `*pnum = '9';` will probably modify more memory than that (`int` commonly has size `4`). So if there is 1 byte of memory reserved for the `char` on the stack, what are those other three bytes that it's modifying?

Use a `char*` to point to a `char` instead:

```
int main() {
    char num = 'A';
    char* pnum = &num;
    *pnum = '9';
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
```